# Best practices on resolving references in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've put up a simple example of books, tagged with their genre:

```
var db = require('mongojs').connect('mongo-test', ['tags', 'books']);

db.tags.drop();
db.books.drop();

db.tags.insert([{
    _id: 1,
    name: 'Thriller'
}, {
    _id: 2,
    name: 'Romance'
}, {
    _id: 3,
    name: 'Crime'
}, {
    _id: 4,
    name: 'Comedy'
}]);

db.books.insert([{
    title: 'Book 1',
    tags: [1, 3]
}, {
    title: 'Book 2',
    tags: [2]
}, {
    title: 'Book 3',
    tags: [2, 4]
}]);

db.books.find({}, function (error, result)
{
    // how do I resolve the tag-references?
    console.log(result);
});
```

Now, when I retrieve books I also want to have the full tags and not only their IDs. I don't want to put the tags directly in a book-record because the tag objects will grow in properties.

What is the best practices to resolve those kind of references?

Comment: The best practice for this kind of design is to use a relational database. Because this is relational design.

Comment: There must at least be some approaches for NoSQL databases since MongoDB even documents relationship patterns: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the node.js world, the common practice is to use the [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/index.html) ORM and its support for [population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

Where your query would end up looking like:

```
Book.find({}).populate('tags').exec(function(err, books) {...});
```

Comment: Is there anything simpler than Mongoose? Creating all these schemas seems to be pretty frustrating to me.